# How to validate a custom angular form control after it's touched?

Tags: angular

I have a custom form control, and validation sort of seems to be working, but the `validate` method isn't being called after the control is touched.  In my simple custom form control, I would like to be able to validate any time the control is touched and not just after its value has changed.

How can I make this happen?  Or is there a better way to get an initial validation to occur?

Here's a plunk with an example component (https://plnkr.co/edit/qAWDsH?p=preview).  I'd like the custom component's validation to fail after I touch it.

Here's my custom control:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-custom-control',
  template: `

      <input type="text"
            style="color:red;"
            placeholder="Valid with odd # of characters"
            #input="ngModel"
            [(ngModel)]="text"
            (change)="onInputChanged($event)"
            (blur)="onBlur()"
            (focus)="onFocus()" 
      >

  `,
  providers: [
    CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    CUSTOM_CONTROL_VALIDATOR
  ] 
})
export class MyCustomControl implements ControlValueAccessor, OnChanges, OnInit, Validator {

  @Input() text: string;
  @Input() placeholder: string; 
  @Input() required: any;

  constructor() {

  }

  private onTouchedCallback: () => void = noop;
  private onChangeCallback: (_: any) => void = noop;  

  onBlur() {
    console.log("custom control blur");
    this.onTouchedCallback();
  }

  onFocus() {
    console.log("custom control focus");
    this.onTouchedCallback();
  } 

  onInputChanged() {
    console.log("value changing");
    this.onChangeCallback(this.text);
  }

  //From ControlValueAccessor interface
  writeValue(value: string) {
    this.text = value;
  }

  //From ControlValueAccessor interface
  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    this.onChangeCallback = fn;
  }

  //From ControlValueAccessor interface
  registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
    this.onTouchedCallback = fn;
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
  ngOnChanges() {
    this.onChangeCallback(this.text);
  } 

  // From Validator interface
  validate (c: FormControl) {
    console.log('validating');
    if (this.text.length % 2) 
      return null;

    return { 
      customError: {
        message: "This is not valid",

      }
    }
  }  

}
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://plnkr.co/edit/Zjg6px0dyI4hePtwI7g4?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

you can add keyup event like this

```
  <input (keyup)="onKey($event)">
`
```

in compoent.ts

```
export class Component {

  onKey(event:any) { 
    console.log('event', event);
  }
}
```

Comment: But I don't want to have to type a key.  I just want validation to happen when the control is touched.  Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @ChrisFarmer I want the same functionality, Did you got any solution?